# Python package No module ImportError

Tags: python

Environment: Ubuntu 14

The structure:

```
test
├── a
│   ├── a.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── b
│   ├── b.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── __init__.py
```

In "b.py":

```
import test.a.a
```

if I run "python b.py":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 1, in <module>
    import test.a.a
ImportError: No module named a.a
```

Comment: Sorry, those flags were belongs to my last question but I forgot to change...

Comment: It looks like you're inside the `b` directory when you run your script. You need to either run it from `test` or edit your path to include `a`.

Comment: Even if I move the working directory to the test, and then "python b/b.py", but it's the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have several options

**1)** Include the path to the folder test to `sys.path`

you can do hardcoded

b.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append("path/to/test")
import test.a.a
```

but in this case you have to change it manually if later you change the test folder to another place

you can also do automatic with

b.py

```
import os, sys
path = os.path.dirname( os.path.dirname( os.path.dirname(__file__) ) )
#       folder_of_test/     test      /           b
sys.path.append(path)
import test.a.a
```

in this one, if you are using python 2 you need to call `os.path.abspath` on `__file__` first

**2)** Add the `test`'s parent folder to your [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonpath#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable, or put the `test` folder in a folder in your PYTHONPATH or PATH environment variable.

to do this do

```
$> export PYTHONPATH="/path/to/parent/folder/of/test:$PYTHONPATH"
```

but most likely will only be temporal, to do in a permanent way go to the file `.profile` or `.bashrc` in your home folder and put the above instruction in there at the end in your favorite [way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables) (I modify .profile to set my pythonpath)

**3)** Call your code as `python -m test.b.b` from the folder that contain `test`

in any case you have to make sure that you don't other library that have the same name, for example I have anaconda installed and that come with a test package, and in that case you should change the name to avoid confusion

Comment: On the second method, how I can set PYTHONPATH in Ubuntu?

Comment: It seems in this case, I need to set PYTHONPATH  to the parent directory of test?

Comment: yes you add the parent folder. I added how to do it

Answer (score 1):

The module `test` is part of the standard library. So when you `import test.a`, it tries to import the `a` module in it.

So, even if you find a solution, it is better you don't use that name for your package.

Comment: Local modules and packages shadow those in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
from test.a import a
```

or with:

```
from ..a import a
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 1, in <module>
    from test.a import a
ImportError: No module named a